# SSRS Report Group by Year and then by Month

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset that has Customer_ID, Event_Date columns. I'm trying to do a report that will show the number of customers attended in a year and then by month in that year.  The Event_Date field is a date field in YYYYMMDD format. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For any date field you can use the Month and Year function the get the specific datepart

```
= Year( Fields!Event_Date.Value )
= Month( Fields!Event_Date.Value )
```

All you have to do is creating 2 groups and set the appropriate expression to each one of them.